# jquery Iterate through ID's to hide/show div

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I am trying to create a div on the bottom a of an image that when clicked, shows and when clicked again, hides. I can get it working with just one of the divs, but I am trying to do this for all of them containing the same ID.

I was first trying to get the div to initially hide and can't. Thanks for any help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $dropdown= $('#project-description');
  $dropdown.hide()
  $('#project-dropdown').each(function(){
    $('#project-dropdown').click(function() {
      if ($menu.is(':visible')) {
        $menu.slideUp("medium", function() {
          $menu.hide();
        });
      }
      else {
        $menu.slideDown("medium");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

UPDATE: I am closer to what I am looking for. It kind of works now that I am using classes, but all of the div's open and close together. Is there any way to get them independent of one another?

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $dropdown = $('.description-dropdown');
  var $container = $('.description-container');
  $dropdown.hide();

  // $($menu).each(function () {
    $($container, $dropdown).click(function () {
      if ($dropdown.is(':visible')) {
        $dropdown.slideUp("medium", function () {
          $dropdown.hide();
        });
      } else {
        $dropdown.slideDown("medium");
      }
    });
  // });
});
```

**Div's being manipulated**

```
<div class="container description-container">
  <div class="ui divider center aligned"><i class="chevron down icon"></i></div>
  <div class="description description-dropdown">
    <p><%- project.description %></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include your HTML.  I sounds like you are using the same `id` on multiple elements.  That's not valid HTML (element `id`s _must_ be unique within a document). If you are trying to target multiple elements with a selector, use a `class` instead.

Comment: Also, could you show the $menu definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make them slide independently you need to have your event code only operate on the element that was clicked. To do that you need to find the dropdown inside the container that was clicked:

```
$($container).click(function () {
    var dd = $(this).find(".description-dropdown");
    if (dd.is(':visible')) {
        dd.slideUp("medium");
    } else {
        dd.slideDown("medium");
    }
});
```

Note that the call to .hide inside .slideUp is not required as slideUp performs a hide.

Comment: Thanks man. Forgot to thank you. This did the trick. Can't upvote because I am too new.

Comment: No worries, glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're trying to use ID's. ID's can only reference to one element and a class should be used in place of that.

Using classes you can set the same class to mutliple elements and then they'll be called when needed.

**Also** when it comes to classes, you use a dot instead of a hash.

Hope this helps you out

```js
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    var $dropdown = $('.project-description');
    var $menu = $('.menu');
    //$dropdown.hide();

    $($dropdown).each(function()
        {
        $($dropdown).click(function()
            {
            if ($menu.is(':visible'))
                {
                $menu.slideUp("medium", function()
                    {
                    $menu.hide();
                    });

                }
            else
                {
                $menu.slideDown("medium");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
 <div class="project-description">
  INFORMATION BLAH BLAH
 </div>

 <br>

 <select class="menu">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
 </select>

 <select class="menu">
  <option value="cake">cake</option>
  <option value="pizza">pizza</option>
  <option value="garlic bread">garlic bread</option>
  <option value="mac n cheese">mac n cheese</option>
 </select>

 <select class="menu">
  <option value="games">games</option>
  <option value="movies">movies</option>
  <option value="music">music</option>
 </select>
</body>
</html>
```